# Changing item orientation in Windows 8 app

Tags: windows, listview, gridview

I am trying to create a Windows 8 calendar like app. I took the basic grid layout template and made some changes to sample data generation so that it generates months and items that represent everyday of the month. My problem is that dates are displayed vertically not horizontally. Trying to understand GridView and ListView, but no luck.

For example:

1 5 8 ..
2 6 
3 7 
4 8

Insetead of displaying:

1 2 3 4 5  
6 7 8 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource"

        IsSourceGrouped="true"
        ItemsPath="SubjectListOfCategory"
         d:Source="{Binding Categories, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:SelectSubjectViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}" />
```

first set your collectionViewSource to datasource in xaml like above. and your grid view like this

```
        x:Name="itemGridView"       
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
       SelectionMode="Multiple"                
        SelectionChanged="itemGridView_SelectionChanged"  >         

        <GridView.ItemTemplate >
            <DataTemplate >
                <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#7b579b"  >
                    <Grid Name="tile" Background="#FFFFFF" Height="150" Width="150"   >
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="hello2" Text="{Binding SubjectName}" Foreground="White" FontSize="15" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="8"   FontWeight="ExtraLight" />                           
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>

        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="98,0,0,0"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <GridView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,6"  >
                            <Button
                                AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                                Style="{StaticResource TextPrimaryButtonStyle}">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryName}" Margin="2" FontSize="30" Foreground="White" FontWeight="Light" />

                            </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VariableSizedWrapGrid  Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,80,0" MaximumRowsOrColumns="3"   />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
            </GroupStyle>
        </GridView.GroupStyle>
    </GridView>
```

now in your xaml.cs do this.

```
 objselectsubjectViewmodel = new SelectSubjectViewModel();
        groupedItemsViewSource.Source = objselectsubjectViewmodel.Categories;
        this.DataContext = this;
```

here objselectsubjectViewmodel.Categories is your datamodel..
just give it little bit time.